# Arrays of DataFrames

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I create an array of DataFrames?
This is `cc01`, the remaining `ccXX`s look the same:

[image]

And, this is my try:

```
i = 0
for ccXX in [cc01, cc02, cc03, cc04, cc05]:
    i += 1
    deltas[i] = ccXX.iloc[[10, 20],[-2, -1]]
```

Comment: What do u exactly mean by an array of dataframes?

Comment: @Vaebhav Like having a 3D matrix. Right now I have 5 DataFrames, but this could escalate. That's why I want to automatize the whole process.

Comment: Instead of doing `i+=1` in the for loop, just `for i, ccXX in enumerate(your_list)`. Note that `i` in `enumerate` is zero-indexed